# FluentD regex parsed values not appearing in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

So I saw there were a few other questions of this type, but none seemed to solve my issue.

I am attempting to take Springboot logs from files, parse out useful information, and send the result to Elasticsearch, and ultimately read from Kibana.  My fluentd.conf looks like the following:

```
<source>
  type tail
  read_from_head true
  path /path/to/log/
  pos_file /path/to/pos_file
  format /^(?<date>[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+.[0-9]+)\s+(?<log_level>[Aa]lert|ALERT|[Tt]race|TRACE|[Dd]ebug|DEBUG|[Nn]otice|NOTICE|[Ii]nfo|INFO|[Ww]arn?(?:ing)?|WARN?(?:ING)?|[Ee]rr?(?:or)?|ERR?(?:OR)?|[Cc]rit?(?:ical)?|CRIT?(?:ICAL)?|[Ff]atal|FATAL|[Ss]evere|SEVERE|EMERG(?:ENCY)?|[Ee]merg(?:ency)?)\s+(?<pid>[0-9]+)\s+---\s+(?<message>.*)$/
  tag my.app
</source>
<match my.app>
 type stdout
</match>
<match my.app>
 type elasticsearch
 logstash_format true
 host myhosthere
 port 9200
 index_name fluentd-app
 type_name fluentd
</match>
```

Given a typical Springboot log line:

```
2015-07-16 19:20:04.074 INFO 16649 --- [ main] {springboot message}
```

By also writing to stdout as a test, I see my parser is resulting in:

```
{
 "date":"2015-07-16 19:20:04.074",
 "log_level":"INFO",
 "pid":"16649",
 "message":"[ main] {springboot message}"
}
```

However, when this gets written to Elasticsearch, all that results is:

```
{
 _index: "fluentd-app-2015.07.16",
 _type: "fluentd",
 _id: "AU6YT5sjvkxiJXWCxeM8",
 _score: 1,
 _source: {
  message: "2015-07-16 19:20:04.074 INFO 16649 --- [ main] {springboot message}",
  @timestamp: "2015-07-16T19:20:04+00:00"
 }
},
```

From what I had read about [fluentd-plugin-elasticsearch](https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch) I expected _source to contain all of the parsed fields that I see in stdout.  I have also tried the grok parser - though it seems apparent the issue lies with understanding of the fluentd elasticsearch plugin.  How do I get the fields I parsed to persist to elasticsearch?

Comment: Your regex includes a newline `\n` after the anchor. If a newline is not there in the text, it will fail. And, the anchors `^$` _can_ be used in a multi-line mode search. Is that how its used? Either way, I would take that `\n` out. I would even take out the '$' as well. This assumes the Dot `.` metachar doesn't match line-breaks.

Comment: This appears to be an artifact of how the code was posted here - each Springboot log actually only takes up a single line.  When I run fluentd in verbose mode `fluentd -c fluentd.conf -v` I can see my regex works, because it no longer warns "pattern not match:" like it used to.  Instead, it shows me the JSON format resulting from the parse, as I show above.  For some reason this resulting JSON does not get sent to elasticsearch.

Comment: What I mean is that each log line is a single line that terminates in a line break.  I am able to verify that the regex is indeed working due to the stdout output showing the corresponding parsed JSON that I expect.  What is not working is passing that properly formed JSON response to Elasticsearch using the elasticsearch plugin for fluentD.

Comment: I see, sorry about that ..